# Может ли бот тегать 2 участников в сообщении?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, telebot, python-3.8

Здраствуйте. Вот такой вопрос у меня появился. Я хочу сделать развлекательного бота для беседы со своими друзьями. Так вот, во многих ботах присутствует функция "Ролевых команд". К примеру участник пишет в ответ на сообщение другому участнику "обнять". А бот в свою очередь должен будет ответить

@ТегПервогоЮзера обнял @ТегВторогоЮзера

Я смог сделать первый тег, но не знаю как сделать второй. Вот мой код. Если есть вопросы, я готов ответить

````
def rrrr(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'обнять':
        tag = message.from_user.username
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"@{tag} обнял")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно. Для того, чтобы сделать такую возможность пользователь должен ответить на сообщение того, к кому конкретное действие применяется.

Проблем в том, что у одного из пользователей юзернейм может быть не установлен, что делать в таком случае? :)

```py
def rrrr(message):
    if message.text.lower() != 'обнять' or message.reply_to_message is None:
        return
    
    from_user = message.from_user # Тот, кто обнимает
    replied_user = message.reply_to_message.from_user # Тот, кого обняли

    if from_user.username is None:
        author = f"{from_user.first_name} {from_user.last_name}"
    else:
        author = f"@{from_user.username}"

    if replied_user.username is None:
        target = f"{replied_user.first_name} {replied_user.last_name}"
    else:
        target = f"@{replied_user.username}"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{author} обнял {target}")
```

Можно придумать что-то лучше...

Comment: Cпасибо, но я еще видел, как другие боты игнорируют то, что у участника отсутствует юзернейм, но они все равно как-то тегают. Ирис этому пример, но все равно спасибо огромное! Вы очень часто мне помогаете!

Comment: Если вам не сложно, а для чего нужна часть if? Типо, какая ее цель?

Comment: if - это условие **если**, в любом языке программирования. Кстати да, если нет юзернейма то можно брать имя + фамилия в телеграме, почему нет

Comment: Обновил код, теперь, если у одного из пользователей нет юзернейма, то берутся его имя и фамилия

Comment: Я знаю, что такое if, хотя если вы изменили код, то тему можно опустить, спасибо за помощь ;)